# Remove duplicate lines only if the duplicate items are within 5 lines of each other

Tags: awk

I want to delete the duplicate lines of a text file only if the duplicate items are within 5 lines of each other.

For example :

```
Chapter 1.1
Overview
Figure 1
Figure 2
Overview <- This should be deleted (ie. within 5 lines of the previous instance) 
Figure 3
Figure 4
...

(many lines in between)

Chapter 1.2
Overview <- This should not be deleted (ie. not within 5 lines of the previous instance)
```

I tried to use `awk '!a[$0]++'` but this will delete all the duplicates lines on the entire file. I also tried with a loop and `sed -n "$startpoint,$endpoint p" file.txt | awk '!a[$0]++'` but this actually creates new duplicates...

What other approaches can I try to remove the duplicates lines that are within 5 lines of each other?

Comment: If, in your sample input, `Figure 4` were followed by `Overview`, would it be deleted too? And it's not only `Overview` but any string, right?

Comment: Yes. If ```Figure 4``` were followed by ```Overview``` it should be deleted too. It is not only ```Overview``` but any duplicated string that is separated by 5 lines or less, that should be deleted.

Comment: Would that be deleted due to the first `Overview`, or also due to the deleted one? Also, if you had `A` 10x`B` `A` would that result in `A` `B` or `A` `B` `A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach you could try is keeping the preceding four lines in a variable and searching the current one in it. Something like:

```sh
awk '{
  idx = index(buf, $0 "\n")
  if (!idx)
    print
  else if (idx != 1 && substr(buf, idx - 1, 1) != "\n")
    print
  if (NR > 4)
    sub(/[^\n]*\n/, "", buf)
  buf = buf $0 "\n"
}' file
```

For something less wobbly and cumbersome, see [this answer](/a/67996878/10248678).

Answer (score 14):

You may use this *shorter* `awk` command:

```sh
awk '!NF || NR > rec[$0]; {rec[$0] = NR+5}' file

Chapter 1.1
Overview
Figure 1
Figure 2
Figure 3
Figure 4
...

(many lines in between)

Chapter 1.2
Figure 1
Figure 2
Overview
```

**Algorithm Details:**

- `!NF || NR > rec[$0];`: Print each record if current line is empty OR if current record number is greater than the value we have in array `rec` for current record. When `$0` doesn't exist in `rec` then also line will be printed. Line will not be printed only when we are within `5` lines from stored value in `rec`.
- `{rec[$0] = NR+5}`: Save each record in array `rec` with value as `current line no + 5`

Comment: Nice solution. It's not clear why blank lines should be special-cased though - I don't see anything in the question to suggest that.

Comment: Yes that was not obvious but I made an assumption that OP may still want to keep all the blank lines  between different sections for readability.

Comment: @Pierre: Remove `!NF ||` from code above if you don't want to keep all blank lines shown in input.

Comment: Say line 1, 5, and 9 are identical. Will both 5 and 9 be removed, or only 5?

Comment: @Deduplicator: As per OP both line #5 and line #9 would be deleted.

Answer (score 4):

***1st solution:*** A single Input_file pass solution.

```
awk '
{
  arr[FNR]=$0
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++){
    count=0
    for(j=i;j>=(i-5);j--){
      if(arr[i]!=arr[j]){ count++      }
    }
    if(count==5)        { print arr[i] }
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With your shown samples and a 2 pass of Input_file; one could try following also. Fair warning it could be slow for if dataset is huge.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[FNR]=$0
  next
}
{
  count=0
  for(i=FNR;i>=(FNR-5);i--){
    if($0!=arr[i]){ count++ }
  }
  if(count==5)    { print   }
}
' Input_file Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                            ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                         ##Checking condition which will be true 1st time Input_file is being read.
  arr[FNR]=$0                    ##Creating arr with index of current line number and value is current line.
  next                           ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  count=0                        ##Nullifying count here.
  for(i=FNR;i>=(FNR-5);i--){     ##Running a loop here for 5 count.
    if($0!=arr[i]){ count++ }    ##Checking condition if current line is not equal to array value then increase count with 1 here.
  }
  if(count==5)    { print   }    ##Checking condition if count is 5 then print line.
}
' Input_file Input_file          ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

---

---

***3rd solution:***

```
awk '!arr[$0]++;++count==5{delete arr;count=0}' Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** 1st and 2nd solution considers that one wants to compare each line with  its next 5 lines(eg: 1-6, 2-7 and so on....). Where 3rd solution considers that one wants to remove duplicate within each set of 5 lines(eg: 1-5, 6-10 and so on....)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use an array of 5 variables, initialized to `(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)`.

In a loop, you read the file line by file, and:

- you shift the array by one position, e.g. `a[0] = a[1], a[1] = a[2], ..., a[4] = a[5]`
- you set the last element (`a[5]`) to `1` if the line matches the string (e.g. with `grep`), or to `0` otherwise
- if the array contains `1`, you skip the line, otherwise you print it

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{f=0; for (i in a) if (a[i]==$0) {f=1; break} a[NR%5]=$0} !f' file
```

This keeps an array containing the previous 5 lines. The current line is only printed if it is not found in the array.